# Cannot convert value of type ... in coercion

Tags: ios, swift3

Here is my error in swift 3.0

Cannot convert value of type `(_, NSError?) -> Void' to type 'GMSAutocompletePredictionsCallback' (aka '(Optional<Array<GMSAutocompletePrediction>>, Optional<Error>) -> ()')` in coercion

Here is my code

[image: Please follow this link to view code]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you have code to share with us, please don't post it as image. You can add it to your post and [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying that `GMSAutocompletePredictionsCallback` contains object of `Error` type not `NSError`, As of in Swift 3 you need to use `Error` instead of `NSError`, so just simply change your error type to `Error?` instead of `NSError?`.